# How to write "Big Data" to a text file using Matlab

Tags: matlab, arduino, text-files, serial-communication, read-write

I am getting some readings off an accelerometer connected to an Arduino which is in turn connected to MATLAB through serial communication. I would like to write the readings into a text file.  A 10 second reading will write around 1000 entries that make the text file size around 1 kbyte.

I will be using the following code:

```
%%%%%// Communication %%%%%
arduino=serial('COM6','BaudRate',9600);
fopen(arduino);
fileID = fopen('Readings.txt','w');

%%%%%// Reading from Serial %%%%%
for i=1:Samples
    scan = fscanf(arduino,'%f');
    if isfloat(scan),
        vib = [vib;scan];
        fprintf(fileID,'%0.3f\r\n',scan);
    end
end
```

Any suggestions on improving this code ?  Will this have a time or Size limit?   This code is to be run for 3 days.

Comment: the Formatting was actually my way of trying to make it easier for people tio read, it was an attempt people are not perfect @Adriaan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not use text files, use binary files. `42718123229.123123` is 18 bytes in ASCII, 4 bytes in a binary file. Don't waste space unnecessarily. If your data is going to be used later in MATLAB, then I just suggest you save in `.mat` files
2. Do not use a single file! Choose a reasonable file size (e.g. 100Mb) and make sure that when you get to that many amount of data you switch to another file. You could do this by e.g. saving a file per hour. This way you minimize the possible errors that may happen if the software crashes 2 minutes before finishing.

Comment: Its a very good idea of not writing into one file only, i will iterate and write into different files as you suggested when files reach a certain size.
i am now looking into the Binary files, thank you

Comment: 10 second = 1kb, 3 days = 259,200 seconds. So your final data size should be something like 25.92 MB - not going to be that big, but @AnderBiguri is right, you should always save your data that is streaming into smaller chunks/batches (might also be worth just saving a copy raw just in case the result Matlab outputs is contaminated/wrong)

Comment: @GameOfThrows Oh, I didn't realize the size was that small. But indeed, as you say, just for safety reasons, better to save time to time

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yeah, when "Big Data" was highlighted, I thought it was going to be in the range of multiple Gigs at least...

Comment: @AnarKi , as GameOfThorws suggest: Generally , the idea of BIg Data is data so big that a normal computer can not store it. 26Mb can be stored easily.

Comment: @AnderBiguri True, i didnt do the calculations for that but i should mention this that the 25.92Mb is for one axis of only 1 accelerometer, there are a multiple accelerometers and i want to save all 3 axis data, so it will be around 200Kb per minute meaning it will be around 288Mb a day

Comment: @AnarKi Then its more reasonable. If any of the answers helped you, consider upvoting/accepting them, for future readers

Answer (score 1):

Now knowing the real dimensions of your problem, writing a text file is totally fine, nothing special is required to process such small data. But there is a problem with your code. You are writing a variable `vid` which increases over time. That may cause bad performance because you are not using preallocation and it may consume a lot of memory. I strongly recommend not to keep this variable, and if you need the dater read it afterwards.

Another thing you should consider is verification of your data. What do you do when you receive less samples than you expect? Include timestamps! Be aware that these timestamps are not precise because you add them afterwards, but it allows you to identify if just some random samples are missing (may be interpolated afterwards) or some consecutive series of maybe 100 samples is missing.

Comment: Is there a way to preallocate the size other than just estimating and adding a bit to the estimation of what it think the size would be after 3 days of consecutive running ?

Comment: Is it really intended to keep all data you read in memory? I would suggest not to do that and instead use the written file for analyse purposes.

Comment: You mean write directly to a .mat file everytime i scan something from serial right ?

Comment: You already have your text file, why not simply parse it again?

Comment: i didnt save into a text file yet, so i am looking into how should i save the data. i will just append a .mat file

Comment: @AnarKi: Whatever format you use, just don't keep all your data in a variable like you did with `vib`